# Keycloak users - is a good idea to differentiate users by their country?

Tags: keycloak

I'm designing a fairly complex backend and now I have a doubt. Is a good idea in Keycloak to differentiate users in different keycloak groups by their country when I create them during a sign-in for example?

I was thinking that it could be useful to better manage users in the future.
What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct solution for such question. It clearly depends on your application. If in the future your application will provide services based on the country of each user it might be good idea as your application might get this information about the user directly from Keycloak.

If you are planning to do some researches about your users it also might be good idea as some statistics might be country related or you would like to get country related outputs (to relocate your cloud instances near to majority of your users etc..)

There might be faster database lookups with such additional information but I don't know if Keycloak currently provides functionality for this. On the other hand, if I will sign up to your service while I am chilling on my holidays on the other side of the world from where I usually live your record will be useless. Therefore this action could bring more issues to implementation of your application while you might not need it at all.

If you have no plans for such functionalities there is simply no reason to do such thing. Present web services tend to store more data then they actually need to. For example in majority of recent database leaks you can see **LAST** geological coordination's point stored with each user. While these might be unnecessary for precise advertisements targeting and unnecessary users screening, there is really no reason to store last geological coordination of each user. Such information might change with each user login and should be determined in "runtime". If services do not benefit from such data users are under threat for no reason.

You should determine what is needed by your application and what is not. You should never store or expose any additional information's about your users regardless how well your application is secured.

Comment: I was thinking about this information in case in some countries it was necessary to show different things inside the app than in other countries, or maybe for support the users. For example, I can create different support emails for each country. 
(The country I ask the user directly during his registration and maybe I could do a verification with the mobile number, I do not take anything automatically)